# Initialization of "nested" boost::shared_ptr class members

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I'm trying to write a C++ program that has 3 abstract classes (`Base_A`, `Base_B` and `Base_C`) and each of them has one derived class (respectively `Derived_A`,`Derived_B` and `Derived_C`).

Now, I want to create an object `z` of `Derived_C` (via a `boost::shared_ptr`). To initialize `z` I want to use `y` (via a `boost::shared_ptr`), which is a member of `Derived_B` and to initialize `y` I want to use `x` (via a `boost::shared_ptr`), which in turn is a member of `Derived_A`.

The problem I face is that I want to retrieve the value of the member `K`, which belongs to class `Derived_B`, but the following line

```
std::cout << z->barC->K << std::endl;
```

returns 0.0 instead of 50.0 (as it should be).

What am I missing? Maybe something regarding the initialization of `shared_ptr` members in the constructors of classes `Derived_B` and `Derived_C`?

Here is the code:

//----- A.h -----

```
class Base_A{  
public:  
  double K;  

  Base_A(){};
  Base_A(const double& _K);
  virtual ~Base_A(){};

  virtual double operator()(const double& _S) const = 0;
};

class Derived_A :public Base_A{
public:
  double K;

  Derived_A(const double& _K);
  ~Derived_A(){};

  double operator()(const double& _S)const;
};
```

//----- A.cpp -----

```
Base_A::Base_A(const double& _K)
  :K(_K){};

Derived_A::Derived_A(const double& _K)
  :K(_K){};

double Derived_A::operator()(const double& _S) const {
  return std::max(_S - K, 0.0);
}
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----- B.h -----

```
class Base_B{
public:
  double S;
  double K;
  boost::shared_ptr<Base_A> fooB;

  Base_B(){};
  virtual ~Base_B(){};

  // other pure virtual functions...
};

class Derived_B :public Base_B{
public:
   double S;
   double K;
   boost::shared_ptr<Derived_A> fooD;

   Derived_B(const double& _K, boost::shared_ptr<Derived_A> _fooD);
   ~Derived_B(){};

   // declaration of the pure virtual functions...
};
```

//----- B.cpp -----

```
Derived_B::Derived_B(const double& _K, boost::shared_ptr<Derived_A> _fooD)
  :K(_K){
  fooD = boost::shared_ptr<Derived_A>(_fooD);
};
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----- C.h -----

```
class Base_C{
public:
  boost::shared_ptr<Base_B> barB;

  Base_C(){};
  virtual ~Base_C(){};

  // other pure virtual functions...
};

class Derived_C :public Base_C{
public:
  boost::shared_ptr<Base_B> barC;

  Derived_C(boost::shared_ptr<Base_B> _barC);
  ~Derived_C(){};
  // declaration of the pure virtual functions...
};
```

//----- C.cpp -----

```
Derived_C::Derived_C(boost::shared_ptr<Base_B> _barC){

  barC = _barC;
};
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----- Main.cpp -----

```
void main(){

  double K= 50.0;
  double S= 100.0;

  boost::shared_ptr<Derived_A> x(new Derived_A(K));

  boost::shared_ptr<Derived_B> y(new Derived_B(K,x));

  boost::shared_ptr<Derived_C> z(new Derived_C(y));

  std::cout << z->barC->K << std::endl; // returns 0.0 instead of 50.0
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this answer.

You appear to be redeclaring `double K;` in each class. Each new declaration masks the `K` in the parent class.

You are not reading `K` from `Base_A` you are probably getting it from `Derived_B` but the pointer `z->barC` is to a `Base_B`.

Comment: Thanks @Zan Lynx, I've changed the constructor of `Derived_B` and now it looks like  `Derived_B( boost::shared_ptr<Derived_A> _fooD){ barC = _barC; };`. So in `main` I create a `Derived_B` `member` as `boost::shared_ptr<Derived_B> y(new Derived_B(x));`. Now: `std::cout << y->fooD->K << std::endl;` returns 50.0 correctly, `std::cout << z->barC->K << std::endl;` returns 0 instead of 50.0 and `std::cout << z->barC->fooB->K<< std::endl;` gives `Assertion failed: px != 0, file d:\boost_1_57_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp, line 648`. Thus when I initialize `y` through `x` I am not passing `K`.